# WPF CustomControl - Button won't fire Click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command, custom-controls

I created some sort of a square button as a CustomControl with bindings and stuff to "re-gain some programming skill" (learning purpose).

Now I ran into the problem that my custom Commands won't get fired. After I checked everything I could figure out I tested the Click-event directly but even the click-event itself won't get fired.

Custom Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SGDB.Controls.QuadButton"
         x:Name="QButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SGDB.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100" Margin="2,2,2,2">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#003264" Offset="0.25"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#004896" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCD9B" Offset="0.25"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB769" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=IsMouseOver}"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#411902" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
    <Button Width="{Binding Size, ElementName=QButton}" Height="{Binding Size, ElementName=QButton}" Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand, ElementName=QButton}" Click="Button_Click">
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, ElementName=QButton}" Width="64" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText, ElementName=QButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Border>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class QuadButton : UserControl {



    public ICommand ExecuteCommand {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ExecuteCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExecuteCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ExecuteCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExecuteCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ExecuteCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(QuadButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public int Size {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SizeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Size.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Size", typeof(int), typeof(QuadButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public string ImageSource {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Source.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(QuadButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public string DisplayText {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayText", typeof(string), typeof(QuadButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public QuadButton() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

Command in the View that's consuming the Custom Button:

```
<custom:QuadButton Size="200" DisplayText="Administration" ImageSource="../Pictures/Users.png" ExecuteCommand="{Binding VM.TestButton}"/>
```

(VM = ViewModel, TestButton = Command for testing the Buttons)

Comment: Some weird stuff happens when you try to use `Command` and the `Click` event on the same button.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, using your code, but I was not able. Your QuadButton works for me (it raises the click event and then it executes my command). Why do you believe that the click event is not raised?

Comment: When I click on any of my Buttons nothing happens - not even a clicked animation nor my Message Box pops up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my fault - I implemented some Code to make my Window dragable - Now I know that this Method is eating the MouseDown Event.